# Adding Image overlay to button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to create a button toggle using the twitter bootstrap.

What I’m looking to do is add a tick image at the top right of a button when the class active is added.

Here is an example of the source
http://jsfiddle.net/4GC9R/

My button css looks like

```
.mybtn {
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
   margin:5px;
   background:#FBDFDA;
   border:none;
}

.mybtn.active {
    background:#CFCFCF;
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question I’ve tried a few ways but I’m far from a css expert.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the checkmark you could use the `:after` pseudo element and for an image you could then further use `content: url('image_path')` or `background-image: url('image_path')`.
<del>Also, your class selectors should be adjusted.</del> Maybe something in this direction:

```
.mybtn {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:5px;
    background:#FBDFDA;
    border:none;
}

.mybtn.active {
    background:#CFCFCF;
    border:none;
    position:relative;
}
.mybtn.active:after {
    content: '\2713';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4GC9R/2/)

---

**P.S.** if you meant **[tick - as in the animal (e.g. *Ixodes*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick)**, that is also possible via `content` or the `background` property of the `:after` pseudo element ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4GC9R/3)) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When the class name '.active' is added to the button with class '.mybtn', then the selector of the button will not be '.mybtn .active', but '.mybtn.active'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks I've updated the source. Still unsure how to add the tick overlay image.

Comment: Check the :after selector Martin Turjak suggested. Instead of content, you could use the property 'background-image' as well.